Creating two connected arcs
I am using a 2D mapping application and I want to create a shape like this on the map:
 where the red arc and blue arc would be two separate arcs that I need to create and connect them.
Here is the info I have available:

The center point in decimal degrees (the point between the two arcs) which would be about where this red dot is 
Angle of the inner arc in degrees
Angle of the outer arc in degrees
Distance between the two arcs (unit doesn't matter, I can convert between whatever)
Heading (not sure if necessary. I can just rotate the shape after to match the heading)

Is it possible to do this with the information given? Once I can correctly get the two arcs it's simple enough to "connect" them.

Since the center point is geographic, are the other as well? Cartesian arcs don't look like arcs in geographic coordinate system.

@Vince a little new to all this, but not sure what you mean if the other points are geographic too. The map is using the WGS84 coordinate system if that helps.

It is also necessary to decide on the implementation, i.e. choose a programming language or GIS software...

Geographic coordinates are angular measures, so an arc in Cartesian space isn't an arc in geodetic space.
